# Inner object vs denormalization in Elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I need to know which one will be faster and why.

Case 1 :  inner Objects

```
 {
  "name":"Zach",
  "car":{
    "make":"Saturn",
    "model":"SL"
  }
}
```

Case 2 :

```
{
  "name":"Zach",
  "carmake":"Saturn",
  "carmodel":"SL"
}
```

I have gone through the link https://www.elastic.co/blog/managing-relations-inside-elasticsearch, It says that inner object are fast. But is it faster than denormalized objects? Why there is always one to one relationship b/w name and car.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to read https://www.elastic.co/blog/managing-relations-inside-elasticsearch more carefully. It has answers to all your questions. It mentions that internally inner objects are all flattened. Hence both versions are exactly the same with respect to performance.